# Edit the tinymce plugin files in MOODLE

Tags: tinymce, moodle

I want to customize the `insert/edit image` popup in **tinymce editor** in **Moodle**.
The requirement is shown below as image:

[image]

That is I want to add a `new tab` next to `Advanced tab`, and want to add some `message/text/fields` etc. You can get my requirement from the above image.

My problem is **I don't know which file is to edit**. I tried some files but no effect/change is displayed.

My folder structure is:

[image]

`plugins` contains `moodleimage` and other folders
`tiny_mce` contains `3.5.11\plugins\advimage` and more folders

I tried here also..but no luck..

So please someone help me to find the files to make the changes.

My **Moodle** `version` is: **2.9**

Answer (score 0):

Go into:

```
<your_moodle_installation>/lib/editor/tinymce/plugins/moodleimage/tinymce/image.htm
```

and go to the line 46 (or around it):

```
<li id="advanced_tab" aria-controls="advanced_panel"><span><a href="javascript:mcTabs.displayTab('advanced_tab','advanced_panel');" onmousedown="return false;">{#advimage_dlg.tab_advanced}</a></span></li>
```

Just copy and paste it in the line below. 
If you open your tinymce editor you will see that the "Advanced" tab is doubled.

Go and customize it;-)